# 'pdflatex' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: auctex

came across on windows 10 the following error message

```
Running `LaTeX' on `test_latex' with ``pdflatex  -file-line-error   -interaction=nonstopmode "test_latex.tex"''
**'pdflatex' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**
```

however, i do add the executable to the exec-path in init.el , as below:

```
(when (system-is-windows)
  (setq exec-path '(
            "C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64")
   )
)
```

and the path `"C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64"` is also added to environment PATH variable.

Any help/hint is much appreciated!

Comment: the value of (executable-find "latex") should be a valid file. If not you should consider checking your MikTeX installation.

Comment: Your exec path is wrong, it must end with ;%PATH%. Probably it is no need of that, but I am not a MiKTeX user.

Comment: Thank you @gigiair.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out - it turned out that there is `(setenv "PATH" "C:/Users/user/")` at the beginning of the .init file. commented out this line and works fine now. It basically overwrote the windows environment PATH variable. (It also broke my Spyder launch).

I forgot why I added that line in the first place. but adding the path `"C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64"` to the windows environment PATH variable is one way to let Emacs know where to find tex related .exe